# Autowiring service in self instantiated HorizontalLayout

Tags: java, spring, service, vaadin, autowired

Is there a common way to pass an autowired service to a self instantiated view? Let's say we have a VerticalLayout managed by Spring (@Autowired works) and a HorizontalLayout a buttons inside. We need to create multiple instances of the HorizontalLayout and the button performs some action of the service (@Autowired doesn't work, Service is null). What is the best practice to solve this problem? Just pass the service as a parameter to the constructor of the HorizontalLayout is an option, but perhaps there is a better way.

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    public void someMethod(){
    // do something
    }
}

@SpringView(name = "SomeView")
@ViewScope
public class SomeView extends VerticalLayout {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    public SomeView(){
        addComponent(new Subview());
        addComponent(new Subview());
    }
}

public class SubView extends HorizontalLayout {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    public SubView(){
        Button btn = new Button("Test");
        btn.addClickListener(e->service.someMethod());
        addComponent(btn);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I added a code example. Objects of SubView get null for service. A solution would be to pass the service to the constructor. But I wanted to know, if there is a better solution.

Comment: Are you asking *why* it is null, or how to do it without passing references via constructor? If it's the latter you may want to include a simplified version of your code.

Comment: I added a code sample. I wanted to know how to access the service without passing references, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a Vaadin View or just a regular Component? A View must implement the View interface (*com.vaadin.navigator.View*) and thus you can use the constructor to Autowire the Service and the enter() method to create your ui:

```
@SpringView(name = "SomeView")
@ViewScope
public class SomeView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private SomeService service;

    @Autowired
    public SomeView(SomeService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override 
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        //service is available here
        removeAllComponents();
        addComponent(new Subview());
        addComponent(new Subview());
    }
}
```

The way it works is that Spring will instantiate SomeView and in the process it will autowire your service through the constructor. Then, whenever the View is called it will use the *enter()* method to draw its components.

If it's just a regular component (I think that is your case), then instead of *enter()* use the **@PostConstruct** annotation in a method. For example:

```
@Autowired
public SomeView(SomeService service){
    this.service = service;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    //service is available here
    addComponent(...);
}
```

I haven't tested this annotation but it's widely [documented in Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/10674/III+-+Views+and+Navigation+with+Vaadin+Spring). Please let me know if it works for you.